# Can I use extern function declaration on a C Header which is also used for the C source file which contains the function definition?

Tags: c, header-files, c89

I have the following source code in C89:

**routine_a.c**:

```
struct DataRoutineA routineA(int a, int b) {
  struct DataRoutineA data = (struct DataRoutineA *) malloc(sizeof(DataRoutineA));
  data.a = a;
  data.b = b;
  return data;
}
```

and the following header file:

**routine_a.h**:

```
struct DataRoutineA {
  int a;
  int b;
};

extern struct DataRoutineA routineA(int a, int b);
```

The intention of `routine_a.h` is that it could be used as header for other source code files. Hence the struct is defined and also the extern function definition. In that case my understanding is that the header is properly defined.

However, what happens with the extern clause if this header is also used for `routine_a.c`? Which was the way to fix this in ANSI C/C89? Do I need two different headers for this case?

Comment: it's perfectly valid to include routine_a.h in routine_a.c. In contrary `gcc` has an option to create a warning if there is **no** extern declaration for non-static functions defined in a translation unit

Comment: Does not the "extern" clause mess anything? -I have tried to find references to this case in K&R The C Programming Language book without success-

Comment: no it doesn't mess anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions in C are by default extern. So there is no difference between

```
extern struct DataRoutineA routineA(int a, int b);
```

and

```
struct DataRoutineA routineA(int a, int b);
```

You do need the `extern` keword when declaring function prototypes at all.

Comment: So I could remove the extern clause and use the header both in `routine_a.c` and in `routine_x.c`. The extern clause only applies to variables then?

Comment: Yes - but not exactly. As I wrote functions are extern be default - so the `extern` keyword is not needed and both definitions are exactly the same.